# delete from gridview using checkboxs

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi gusy im trying to anderstand how delete from database using grindview with checkboxs but i dont know why deleteresults.text and DeleteResults.Visible  dont work this is my code (im new in programming :) and thx for your answers

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool atLeastOneRowDeleted = false;
    // Iterate through the Products.Rows property
    foreach (GridViewRow row in Products.Rows)
    {
        // Access the CheckBox
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("selector");
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {
            // Delete row! (Well, not really...)
            atLeastOneRowDeleted = true;
            // First, get the ProductID for the selected row
            int id_offre = Convert.ToInt32(Products.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
            // "Delete" the row
            DeleteResults.Text += string.Format("This would have deleted ProductID {0}<br />", id_offre);
        }
    }
    // Show the Label if at least one row was deleted...
    DeleteResults.Visible = atLeastOneRowDeleted;

}
```

Comment: So what is happening and not happening? Is there an error or just not doing anything?

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: i run the webpage and i click on the checkbox then i click o delete i have error in the line   int id_offre = Convert.ToInt32(Products.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);   " indexis out of limites cant be negative"

Comment: So which part of the line is null? `DataKeys`? `row.RowIndex`? Or `.Value`? My guess is `row.RowIndex`.

Comment: i dont know really im folwing a tuto to do this i copied this code but its not working :(

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger to set break points in your code?

Comment: no :( can you explaine me what this line do ?

Comment: What tutorial are you following? Link please.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/adding-a-gridview-column-of-checkboxes-cs

Comment: and i dont have the same DB i hae a table called "offres" if thats help

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `DataKeyNames` property on your `GridView`? You need to do that to use `DataKeys[index]`. According to MSDN, when you set the `DataKeyNames` property, the `DataKeys`  object gets populated. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys(v=vs.100).aspx. Try setting that property, read more on that [on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)